# Поиск совпадений в базе

Tags: база-данных, php

Здравствуйте. Как сделать поиск информации из базы данных вида POST: Привет мир,
находил статью у которой ключевое слово МИР. LIKE '%Привет мир%' не катит. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Уточните вопрос: что вы уже сделали для поиска? Приведите ваш вариант таблицы в базе, форму поиска, запрос для поиска, вывод результатов

Comment: Каким образом выделяется ключевое слово? ПОиск просто производится по всем отдельным словам?

Comment: Подсказка: неправильное решение выглядит так:

    $where = 'WHERE UPPER(`text`) LIKE UPPER("%'.
            implode
            (
                '%") OR `text` LIKE UPPER("%',
                preg_split( '/\s+/', 'Привет мир' )
            ).
            '%")';

Comment: В общем пишу бота, который должен отвечать на предложения.
Допустим пользователь написал "бла бла гуглить", надо найти в бд в поле word одно из слов из текста в моём случае "гугл", т.е пользователь может написать любой бред главное чтобы в нём было "гугл*". Короче типо preg_match только через бд.

Comment: Так в чём проблема-то? Входная строка разбивается на слова, а как и с чем эти слова в запросе сопоставлять - зависит уже от конкретики. В лббом случае непонятно что именно из этой банальщины вызывает вопросы.